# getCanonicalFile and getAbsoluteFile returns the current (project) directory instead of the expected one

Tags: java, file

I try to make a simple program that contains the function of browsing local file system.

However, I met a problem when the address is directly input.

```
public void setWorkingDirectory(File newDir)
{
    try
    {
        //try to eliminate redundancy
        this.workingDir = newDir.getCanonicalFile();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        this.workingDir = newDir;
    }
}
```

I need the absolute path to display on the screen. So I use `getCanonicalFile()`. Everything works fine except that when I input "D:" the workingDir will be set to the current project directory in Eclipse (I think it should be the current directory when executed independently, the example is "D:\EclipseWorkspace\workspace\FTPClient") but the File newDir contains exactly the same path ("D:") (I traced it).

If I input "C:" or "D:\", then everything is fine. I couldn't find any information about this on the Internet. Could anyone tell me what's going on here and how to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I work on Windows XP SP3 with Java 6 if that matters.

Comment: Although you're working with Windows, replace all of your backslashes with forward slashes.`"\"` might escape a character after it and you don't want that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It's a good idea. But I think in my case it not necessary since the path is not hard-coded.

Comment: I've uploaded an answer that explains what Kris said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path command

```
D:
```

indicates a change to the *currently selected* directory on disk **D**.

Whereas

```
D:\
```

indicates a change to the *root directory* of disk **D**.

This is basic Windows, you'd get the same results in a (CMD) console window.

If it really is an issue, you'd need to look at the filename and see if it terminates with a `File.separator` and if not, append one.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it in cmd... I never noticed it before. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not really know how to explain it, the `getCanonicalFile()` uses the `getCanonicalPath()` which is essentially calls the `FileSystem.canonicalize(String path)` method (this is an abstract method).

In Windows, the `java.io.Win32FileSystem.canonicalize(String path)` (which extends `java.io.FileSystem`) calls, essentially, one of the 2 *native* methods:

```
protected native String canonicalize0(String path)
```

OR

```
protected native String canonicalizeWithPrefix0(String canonicalPrefix, String pathWithCanonicalPrefix)
```

So, as Kris says, it's basic Windows function.

Comment: Thank you for your details. That's helpful.